# Declaring layout explanation Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, xml

I need someone who explains something to me in the layout that I didn't understand.

I know that when I create some layout.xml I declare it like:
for exemple:

```
<custom_account_login> //layout handle <router_nameController_methodAction>
    <reference name="content"> //content block when i display my block
        <block type="core/template" name="name.block" template="custom/cus.phtml"> // the template path of my file
    </reference>
</custom_account_login>
```

Right? but in this one i didn't understand what he do

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <customer_account_edit> //layout handle <router_nameController_methodAction>
        <reference name="customer_edit"> // ?
            <action method="setTemplate"> //?
                <template>stackexchange_customer/form/edit.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_edit>
    <customer_account_create>//layout handle <router_nameController_methodAction>
        <reference name="customer_form_register"> //?
            <action method="setTemplate"> //?
                <template>stackexchange_customer/register.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_create>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <customer_account_edit> //layout handle <router_nameController_methodAction>
        <reference name="customer_edit"> // Name of the reference block you want to update
            <action method="setTemplate"> // Name of the handler you want to call
                <template>stackexchange_customer/form/edit.phtml</template>// Argument to pass in above setTemplate method
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account_edit>
    <customer_account_create>//layout handle <router_nameController_methodAction>
        <reference name="customer_form_register"> // Name of the reference block you want to update 
            <action method="setTemplate"> //Name of the handler you want to call
                    <template>stackexchange_customer/register.phtml</template>
                </action>
            </reference>
        </customer_account_create>
    </layout>
```

Magento allows you to update your layout with XML configuration.
You can update template of a particular block like below. Suppose you have a custom layout file with handler `custommodule_index_index`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<custommodule_index_index>
<reference name="content">
<block type="custommodule/custommodule" name="custommodule" template="custommodule/custommodule.phtml" />
</reference>
</custommodule_index_index>
</layout>
```

Here default template file for this handler is `custommodule/custommodule.phtml` Now you want to call a new template file for this handler then you can do it with reference name of the block like,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <layout>
        <custommodule_index_index>
            <reference name=" custommodule ">
                <action method="setTemplate">
               <template>stackexchange_custom/newfile.phtml</template>
                </action>
            </reference>
        </custommodule_index_index>
    </layout>
```

Now when the action `custommodule_index_index` will fire your new template file `stackexchange_custom/newfile.phtml` will be called instead of `custommodule/custommodule.phtml`
Things you can do with layout files are,

- Set the page layout
- Include static resources (JavaScript, CSS, fonts) in
- Remove static resources (JavaScript, CSS, fonts) in
- Create a container
- Reference a container
- Create a block
- Set a block’s template
- Modify block arguments
- Reference a block
- Use block object methods to set block properties
- Rearrange elements
- Remove elements
- Replace elements

Magento will look at the type of the parent or referenced block, and will attempt to call the action method.
Different blocks can have different action methods.
[Reference](https://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/magento-layout-xml-action-method-reference/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however i dont know we can retreive the reference name of this handle. It works if we replace the reference name with root or content because i have the layout handle tag befor ?

Comment: Added more details. Please check.

Comment: Thanks @Jaimin Sutariya's answer now i understand well, the reference name in my exemple customer_edit is a block type of the module that i wanted update.